# Unable to execute LINQ and Functions within an Expression<Func<T,Y>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to sum up all the child Quantity values which is in a list. Methods are not executing within this function, the code below just returns 0 and no logic is executed, what might be the best option to
sum these values?

initial call to `ProjectToViewModel()`

```
Result<IQueryable<PurchaseOrderGridViewModel>> result = _ownedEntityRepository.GetQueryable(User, selectedEntity, ProjectToViewModel(PurchaseOrderGridViewModel.LoggedUserTimeZoneId), IncludesForViewModel());
```

Lamda thats not executing within ProjectToViewModel().
`purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Sum(c => c.Quantity) + 20`
NOTE: Only lamdas and functions aren't working, normal usage like:
 `ItemsReceived = purchaseOrder.SomeDecimalField` works fine

```
 public Expression<Func<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderGridViewModel>> ProjectToViewModel(string loggedUserTimeZoneId)
        {
            return purchaseOrder => new PurchaseOrderGridViewModel
                                    {
                                        ItemsReceived = purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Sum(c => c.Quantity) + 20,
                                        ItemsNotReceived = purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Select(b => b.Quantity).Sum(),

            };
        }
```

`PurchaseOrder` is the model, `LinkedGrvs` is an `IReadOnlyList<T>` which contains a list of Items and within this list of items i have the quantities for each item. ItemsReceived and ItemsNotReceived are int dataType.

Basically this is what i am trying to do using the above lamda:

```
public int ItemsReceived(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
    {
        if (purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.Count > 0)
        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.Count; i++)
            {
                total = Convert.ToInt32(purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs[i].Items.Sum(c => c.Quantity));
            }
            return total;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

this is my `PurchaseOrderGridViewModel`:

```
    public class PurchaseOrderGridViewModel : IOwnedEntityGridViewModel
        {

            public decimal ItemsReceived { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemsPartiallyReceived { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemsNotReceived { get; set; }
}
```

this is my `PurchaseOrder` model:

```
 public class PurchaseOrder : OwnedAggregateRoot
{
    [JsonIgnore] private readonly List<Grv> _linkedGrvs = new List<Grv>();
    [JsonIgnore] public virtual IReadOnlyList<PurchaseOrderItemLink> Items => _items.ToList();
    [JsonIgnore] public virtual IReadOnlyList<Grv> LinkedGrvs => _linkedGrvs.ToList();
```

my `GetQuerable()`

```
Result<IQueryable<TViewModel>> GetQueryable<TOwnedEntity, TViewModel>(ClaimsPrincipal loggedUser, SelectedEntityOwner selectedEntity,
                                                                          Expression<Func<TOwnedEntity, TViewModel>> selectExpression,
                                                                          Func<IQueryable<TOwnedEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TOwnedEntity, object>> include = null,
                                                                          Expression<Func<TOwnedEntity, bool>> predicate = null,
                                                                          Expression<Func<TOwnedEntity, object>> orderBy = null, bool orderByDescending = false,
                                                                          bool hideInactive = false, bool disableReadOnly = false, bool showVenueEntitiesForGroupUser = false,
                                                                          bool allowDigitotAsSelectedEntity = false)
        where TOwnedEntity : class, IOwnedAggregateRoot
        where TViewModel : class;
```

configuration:

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.LinkedGrvs)
            .WithOne(y => y.PurchaseOrder)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.PurchaseOrderId)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

includes:

```
public Func<IQueryable<PurchaseOrder>, IIncludableQueryable<PurchaseOrder, object>> IncludesForViewModel()
    {
        return x => x
                    .Include(y => y.Group)
                    .Include(y => y.Venue)
                    .Include(y => y.Supplier)
                    .Include(y => y.Items)
                    .Include(y => y.LinkedGrvs)// type IReadOnlyList<Grv> PurchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs
                    .ThenInclude(z => z.Items); // type IReadOnlyList<GrvItemLink> Grv.Items 
    }
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage I'm using LINQ to Objects, the object being IReadOnlyList<T>. Im trying to sum up a field(Quantity) from the lists and return that summed value. I'm using EF Core 3.1. my db provider is SQL server

Comment: @GertArnold I have edited the question to make it more clear. I havn't tried automapper yet i will give it a try.

Comment: If this is LINQ to Objects, you don't need to use `AsQueryable` or `Expression<Func<>>` - you should be able to just use `Func<>`

Comment: C# is a language driven by types. Please show your types / class definitions.

Comment: @NetMage No problem, i have added the class and ViewModel now

Comment: @owen_Ragnarok you didn't show the most important class - the repository and GetQueryable(). In any case, if you use LINQ to any database, you **can't** use anything that can't be translated to SQL. LINQ queries are translated to SQL and there's no way to translate arbitrary functions and even expressions to SQL. If, and only if, the `Expression<Func<>>` is something that can be translated but EF Core fails to do so, you could use LINQKit

Comment: @owen_Ragnarok right now it's impossible to say what's wrong with the repo and the queries, without the actual code. In fact, there's no EF Core code in the question at all. Have you tried just using EF Core *without* any repositories on top? Just `var data=_context.SelectMany(...).Sum()` ? It highly likely that the "repository" is the problem. EF Core doesn't need generic repositories. A DbSet is already a repository, a DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  unfortunately i cannot make drastic changes to the existing codebase however i will try LINQkit, i have also added the `GetQuerable()` above

Comment: @owen_Ragnarok you didn't post any code. The signature doesn't matter. `purchaseOrder.LinkedGrvs.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Sum(c => c.Quantity) ` should just work with any `IEnumerable` - unless your query forgot to eagerly load the related items with `.Include()`. As for making drastic changes, you can't *not* do that if you use a bad design. A "generic" repository over EF Core is a bad design. A *specialized* repository loading the root objects needed in a DDD bounded context is a good design, but that means it has to load *all* the necessary objects

Comment: @owen_Ragnarok EF Core and other ORMs use lazy loading when possible. When you want to edit a customer's address and load `Customer` object you don't get all `Order`s made by that customer. You have to explicitly tell the ORM to load the related entities you want. In EF Core that's done with `Include(po=>po.LinkedGrvs)`. It's also possible to load related entities explicitly, using [Explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) with eg `context.Entry(po).Collection(b => b.LinkedGrvs).Load();`.